# Tagging friends in Facebook videos for an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, facebook, video, tagging

I am developing an iPhone application that allows the uploading of videos to Facebook. I would like to allow the user to tag his/her friends in the video uploaded. How can I achieve this programmatically? I have gone through the Facebook API documentation. There are APIs to add tags to photos, upload videos. But, the API for tagging friends for videos is not mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In the message portion of the API call, you can add the @user to the message to tag specific users. I'd pop a dialog of the users and allow them to "tag" users, then you can populate the end of the message with @John Doe, @Jane Smith etc.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. I will try this out and post my results here.